# Datatables plugin+ajax+java+spring

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring, datatable

Надо передать данные из mysql на страницу в datatables plugin. 
Контроллер:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<Result> getData(){
    return service.findAll();
}
```

Страница:

```
<table id="resultTable" class="dataTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Symbol</th>
        <th>Preis</th>
        <th>PJ</th>
        <th>EJT</th>
        <th>EJH</th>
        <th>T1</th>
        <th>T6</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Symbol</th>
        <th>Preis</th>
        <th>PJ</th>
        <th>EJT</th>
        <th>EJH</th>
        <th>T1</th>
        <th>T6</th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url : "getData",
        dataType : "json",
        type: "POST",
        success : function(json) {
            alert("Success");
            $('#resultTable').dataTable(json);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Json вроде как принимается, но как мне его обработать для datatable?

Comment: пожалуйста расширьте ваш вопрос! Что вы подразумеваете под "обработать для datatable" какой формат джсона ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "getData",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (json) {
            $('#resultTable').DataTable({
                data: json,
                columns: [
                    {data: "name"},
                    {data: "price"},
                    {data: "symbol"},
                    {data: "pj"},
                    {data: "ejt"},
                    {data: "ejh"},
                    {data: "t1"},
                    {data: "t6"}
                ]
            });
        }
    });
});
```